# Multiple viewports into the same Virtual Desktop

Tags: linux, window-manager, virtual-desktop, fvwm

I have been looking around for window manager solutions that would work nicely for me.  While I have found a number of things, I have not yet found anything that really works well for my needs.

Usage patterns:

- A number of "fixed" windows -- firefox, pidgin, a few terminals, that sit around on one monitor and get used.  This is easy, but I don't like having them go away when using desktop switching or whatever.
- A lot of "transient" window that I don't need to have up, or don't need to have up much.  For example, [many] terminal windows doing minute-to-hour-long tasks, graphs I need to show people who will be back "after lunch", documents I will need to reference "once that job finishes", etc.

Currently, this manifests as the first point on one monitor and the second on another.  That means around a dozen terminals, a few document viewers, xmgrace windows, etc. that all are piled up around my desktop.  Making things worse, it's often easier to open a new window (yay right click shortcuts) and ssh into whatever machine I need than it is to find the previous window I was using.

I have been considering using xinput to use a pair of keyboards and mice, because I think that would be convenient.  At the same time, I really like the oversized desktop feature of FVWM.  I think this would allow me to do what I'm looking for.. mostly.

The catch is that I want to let one monitor stay in place, while the other can go wherever it wants.  Effectively I'm looking for multiseat.. but I don't want them isolated from each other.

Comment: I would like to note that "just minimize them" isn't a solution I like.